# Is there a way to force $.toggle() to consistently toggle already hidden children?

Tags: show-hide, jquery

I have an application where data sets can be filtered at various levels, and--for performance reasons--it would be nice to be able to toggle the respective display of nested divs independently. The issue arises in that **toggle will change the display property back to its original state on a hidden child, but it will not change it to none if one of its ancestors is already hidden**.

To replicate: in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GufAW/1/),

1. Click the "toggle 3" button, and then the "toggle 2" button.
2. Clicking the "toggle 3" button and then the "toggle 2", you will find 3 restored (as expected).
3. Now click the "toggle 2" button, then the "toggle 3".
4. On clicking "toggle 2" again, 3 is still visible (???).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

toggle can take a boolean

```
$(selector).toggle(false);
```

---

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

> **.toggle( showOrHide )**
>
> showOrHideA Boolean indicating whether to show or hide the elements.

---

**UPDATE**

You can achieve the functionality you want by creating a simple `hidden` css class calling `toggleClass()` rather than using `toggle()`. `toggle()` seems to skip its own functionality entirely if the element in question is not visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/GufAW/3/

```
$("#toggle-1").click(function() {
    $("#1").toggleClass("hidden");
});
$("#toggle-2").click(function() {
    $("#2").toggleClass("hidden");
});
$("#toggle-3").click(function() {
    $("#3").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: This would always hide them--not make toggle behave consistently, right? "The second version of the method accepts a Boolean parameter. If this parameter is true, then the matched elements are shown; if false, the elements are hidden."

Comment: toggle appears to toggle an element and its children.

Comment: check that... the toggle selector only seems to work on visible/hidden elements. It seems to skip hidden child elements when hiding and skip shown child elements when showing.

Comment: here's my test: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/GufAW/2/ same thing with some more info on the state

Comment: The update is functional, although it would be nice to pass an argument to toggle to make it consistent. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? Make the parent elements add the `hidden` class to its children? What do you mean pass an argument to toggle?

Comment: It would be nice to make toggle always work the same, whether the element is visible or not.

Comment: Ahh, I see. What you could do is wrap what mblase wrote into a new trueToggle() jquery function

Answer (score 1):

Try toggling the css `display` property directly:

http://jsfiddle.net/GufAW/5/

```
$("#toggle-1").click(function() {
    $("#1").css("display", ($("#1").css("display")==="none") ? "block" : "none");
});
$("#toggle-2").click(function() {
    $("#2").css("display", ($("#2").css("display")==="none") ? "block" : "none");
});
$("#toggle-3").click(function() {
    $("#3").css("display", ($("#3").css("display")==="none") ? "block" : "none");
});
```

Comment: This is basically the same trick as hunter's solution, except using more JS and less CSS.